# Getting google search ssl pem certificate

Tags: c++, c, https, openssl, libressl

For testing purpose I want to set up a https connection to google and start a search. I downloaded the OpenSSL example from [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client). In the code, I have to load a pem file here:

```
    /* http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html */
    res = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "random-org-chain.pem", NULL);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();
```

now I search for the certificate of google search. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now I search for the certificate of google search. Where can I get it?

Try Google's Certificate Authority at [Google Internet Authority G2](https://pki.google.com/).

Google runs an unconstrained subordinate CA. The certifying authority is *GeoTrust Global CA*. You can use their CA certificate too.

GeoTrust was purchased by Equifax. So you can also use *Equifax Secure Certificate Authority*.

---

In general, you can see who certifies what with `openssl s_client` and the `-showcerts` option:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect search.google.com:443 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID8DCCAtigAwIBAgIDAjp2MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMEIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
MRYwFAYDVQQKEw1HZW9UcnVzdCBJbmMuMRswGQYDVQQDExJHZW9UcnVzdCBHbG9i
YWwgQ0EwHhcNMTMwNDA1MTUxNTU1WhcNMTYxMjMxMjM1OTU5WjBJMQswCQYDVQQG
EwJVUzETMBEGA1UEChMKR29vZ2xlIEluYzElMCMGA1UEAxMcR29vZ2xlIEludGVy
bmV0IEF1dGhvcml0eSBHMjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB
AJwqBHdc2FCROgajguDYUEi8iT/xGXAaiEZ+4I/F8YnOIe5a/mENtzJEiaB0C1NP
VaTOgmKV7utZX8bhBYASxF6UP7xbSDj0U/ck5vuR6RXEz/RTDfRK/J9U3n2+oGtv
h8DQUB8oMANA2ghzUWx//zo8pzcGjr1LEQTrfSTe5vn8MXH7lNVg8y5Kr0LSy+rE
ahqyzFPdFUuLH8gZYR/Nnag+YyuENWllhMgZxUYi+FOVvuOAShDGKuy6lyARxzmZ
EASg8GF6lSWMTlJ14rbtCMoU/M4iarNOz0YDl5cDfsCx3nuvRTPPuj5xt970JSXC
DTWJnZ37DhF5iR43xa+OcmkCAwEAAaOB5zCB5DAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTAephojYn7
qwVkDBF9qn1luMrMTjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUSt0GFhu89mi1dvWBtrtiGrpagS8wEgYD
VR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwNQYDVR0fBC4wLDAqoCig
JoYkaHR0cDovL2cuc3ltY2IuY29tL2NybHMvZ3RnbG9iYWwuY3JsMC4GCCsGAQUF
BwEBBCIwIDAeBggrBgEFBQcwAYYSaHR0cDovL2cuc3ltY2QuY29tMBcGA1UdIAQQ
MA4wDAYKKwYBBAHWeQIFATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAJ4zP6cc7vsBv6JaE
+5xcXZDkd9uLMmCbZdiFJrW6nx7eZE4fxsggWwmfq6ngCTRFomUlNz1/Wm8gzPn6
8R2PEAwCOsTJAXaWvpv5Fdg50cUDR3a4iowx1mDV5I/b+jzG1Zgo+ByPF5E0y8tS
etH7OiDk4Yax2BgPvtaHZI3FCiVCUe+yOLjgHdDh/Ob0r0a678C/xbQF9ZR1DP6i
vgK66oZb+TWzZvXFjYWhGiN3GhkXVBNgnwvhtJwoKvmuAjRtJZOcgqgXe/GFsNMP
WOH7sf6coaPo/ck/9Ndx3L2MpBngISMjVROPpBYCCX65r+7bU2S9cS+5Oc4wt7S8
VOBHBw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
```